# Lists in C: can't add new elements

Tags: c, list

I have a simple program which initializes a list and adds n elements to it. The problem is that it cannot add the next n-1 elements (it just initializes the list with the first element). I tested the conditions and it seems that the problem is `last->next=elem` from the `add_elem` function. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista {
  int val;
  struct lista *next;
} list;

void allocate(list *p) {
  printf("Alocating memory...");
  p=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
  if(p==NULL) {
    printf("Failed! Exiting program...");
    exit(1);
  } else printf("Done! \n");
}

void init_list(list *first, list *last) {
  printf("Insert first element value: ");
  scanf("%d", &(first->val));
  printf("Initializing list...\n");
  allocate(first);
  first->next=NULL;
  last=first;
  if(first->next==NULL && last==first) {
    printf("Done initializing! \n");
    printf("Last value: %d\n", last->val);
  }
}

void add_elem(list *elem, list *last, int i) {
  printf("Insert the %dth element value: ",i);
  scanf("%d", &elem->val);
  printf("Adding element to list...\n");
  allocate(elem);
  elem->next=NULL;
  last->next=elem;
  last=elem;
  if(elem->next==NULL && last==elem && last->next==elem) {
    printf("Done adding! \n");
    printf("Last value: %d\n", last->val);
  }
  //printf("%d\n", first->next->val);
}

void print_list(list *first) {
  printf("\nCurrent list: \n");
  list *it;
  for(it=first;it!=NULL;it=it->next) {
    printf("%d ",it->val);
  }
}

int main() {
  list first, last, elem;
  int n,i;
  printf("Insert number of elements: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  init_list(&first,&last);
  for(i=2;i<=n;i++) {
    add_elem(&elem,&last,i);
  }
  print_list(&first);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it cannot add the next n-1 elements "  so, what happens? Why do you think that?  Explain.

Answer (score 2):

In your `allocate` function you allocate memory and assign it to the *local* variable `p`. This memory will be lost as changes to local variables are not saved when a function returns.

You also don't *need* to allocate that memory, as you already do it by declaring the lists as non-pointers in the `main` function.

Comment: I should add, even if there were a reason to call `malloc`, in most cases almost every `malloc` call should have an eventual `free` associated with it.  Like most rules there are exceptions to this, but in general it's a good check if you're doing things right.

Comment: i think you need to explain why p is local.

Comment: ok, so I dropped the allocate function since it seems it wasn't necessary, but the issue persists. It adds only the first element to the list through the ` init_list ` function. In the ` if(elem->next==NULL && last==elem && last->next==elem) ` clause, '  last->next==elem ` fails after testing so it seems I can't link the last element to the one I want to add.